# Unable to read manifest error in firefox os simulator

Tags: web-applications, manifest, firefox-os

I have a directory `hello` containing
1.jpg hello.webapp index.html

index.html is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
Hello World!
</body>
</html>
```

hello.webapp is as follow:

```
{
"name": "Hello World",
"description": "blah",
"launch_path": "/index.html",
"icons": {
"128":"1.png"
},
"developer": {
"name": "Richard Sueselbeck"
},
"default_locale": "en"
}
```

but when i add directory to the simulator. It throws an error, unable to read manifest `/home/user/Desktop/hello/hello.webapp`

Comment: What's your root directory in that? As you are putting '/index.html' with root and '1.png' without root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to change in your manifest "1.png" to "1.jpg" ?

Have you tried to rename *hello.webapp* to *manifest.webapp* ? (Good Solution)

Comment: @Shaardool Which one has helped you ?

Comment: The manifest always has to be named "manifest.webapp" not "foo.webapp"

Answer (score 1):

Name of the manifest file should be **manifest.webapp** and it should be in the **root folder** of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification the simulator can't read hello.webapp because the default file for manifest in Firefox OS should be `manifest.webapp`.

Please put code below into new file called `manifest.webapp` in your root directory :

```
{
"name": "Hello World",
"description": "blah",
"launch_path": "/index.html",
"icons": {
"128":"1.png"
},
"developer": {
"name": "Richard Sueselbeck"
},
"default_locale": "en"
}
```

Thanks,